# WordPress move users to a new system

Tags: wordpress

I have a client who has a WordPress website (version 5.1.3 on a custom theme). We are creating a brand new website in c# from scratch and I need to transfer all registered users to the new website.

This can be done fairly easy with the WP API(we use it for posts & categories) but we have an issue with passwords.

As far as I'm aware, WP stores MD5 hashed passwords. C#, of course, supports MD5 encryption and I was thinking to import all users including MD5 hashed passwords. So a user will type in his pass, the website will encrypt it with MD5 and compare with the value we have in the database.

I just need to know the salt key used on the current website? Is this stored somewhere can be extracted?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salts are saved in wp-config.php at your wordpress root.

[Information on wp-config and salts](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/)

[Salt Generator](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/)